# error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist

Tags: java, android, sdk

i'm going to integrate firebase to my android project, but after following the tutorial i found that this error showing up
error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist.
i tried to clean the project,and  i checked update in android . 
this is my build.gradle [module ]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 
'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

   }
```

and this my build.gradle [ project ]

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

please help to solve this problem i spent all this day looking for a solution . thank you

Comment: Are you using a proxy? Is your internet working fine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For latest version **(3.4 or higher)** of Android Studio

Instead of

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppcompatActivity
```

Use this

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppcompatActivity
```

In `MainActivity.java` or in main java file

Answer (score 0):

I think you should Migrate to AndroidX if you want to use `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'` (17.0.0 version) or if you don't want to migrate androdiX use version 16.0.0 `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'`

Comment: add these dependencies `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'` `implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'`
`implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

The c in AppcompatActivity must be in uppercase:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```